# Vector Calculus Problem (related to chain rule, difficult)

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I got some difficulties in solving following problem. The problem is as follows.

Let $h = h(r, t)$ and $R(t)$ satisfy the relation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( r{h}^{3} \frac{\partial h}{\partial r} \right)
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial h}{\partial r} (0, t) = 0, \qquad lim_{r \rightarrow R(t)} h(r,t){(R(t)-r)}^{-1/3} = 1
\end{equation}
In this problem, you may assume that if $f(r, t)$ has continuous partial derivatives than
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{a}^{b} f(r, t) dr = \int_{a}^{b} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(r, t) dr
\end{equation}
(a) Show that $\int_{0}^{R(t)} rh(r, t)dr$ is independent of $t$.

(b) Using the result of (a), when $f$ is continuous and $h(r, t) = f(r/{t}^{\alpha}){t}^{-1/4}$ and $R(t) = k{t}^{\alpha}$ for some constant $k$, find the value of $\alpha$.

For (a), I thought that the integral term would be independent of $t$ if its derivative by $t$ equals $0$, but I failed. Since I failed in (a), I also need some help on problem (b), too. How should I approach the problem?

Comment: It will be easier if you show your steps up to where you couldn't continue, then we could try and understand where you're going wrong

Comment: I tried to differentiate the integral of problem (a) by t to show that it's 0. (Then it is independent to t) So I tried to to use integration by parts, but I couldn't find out how to finish the calculation because of the left integral h(r,t) dr

Comment: One issue I see is you need more than what they've supplied you in terms of the Leibniz rule for integrals, that is $$\frac{d}{dt} \int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} f(r,t) dr = f(b(t),t) b'(t) - f(a(t),t) a'(t) + \int^{b(t)}_{a(t)} \frac{\partial f(r,t)}{\partial t} dr$$